# How To Display Excel rows on selection of first Excel Column Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have Two Excel sheets. My requirement is when I select a reason value from one Excel sheet `Reason_Name` column, it will display that reason value in a second Excel sheet.

So using Macro, I want to display the second Excel rows on selection of reason in first Excel.

Please Help.

This is the first Excel sheet - `Reason_Name` column contains `Reason1`, `Reason2`, etc.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a10d6be7a5.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a10d6be7a5.png)

This is the second Excel sheet

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/99e0ff4cdb.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/99e0ff4cdb.png)

Comment: Is that comic sans being used in the column headers?

Comment: not able to understand your comment, Can you please expalin more

Comment: Only a joke: http://bancomicsans.com/main/

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that may get you started. (I think this is close to what you would like to do.)

Create a [named range](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltips/qt/named_range.htm) for the data on the second sheet. Named "new_range" in my example.

Then create the following procedure in a new module:

```
Sub FilterSheetTwo()

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("new_range").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Reason1"

End Sub
```

When you run this procedure, it should filter the results on `Sheet2`.

You can then hook this procedure up to an `Worksheet_Change` event on `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort your Reason column on the second sheet and place it as the left-most column you don't need a macro--you can do this using VLOOKUP.  Steps:

1. Sort Data by your Reason column on the second sheet.
2. In each column of the first sheet enter the following formula:

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(E2, DataRangeOfSheet2, ColumnYouWantFromDataRange)
   ```

See [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel/HP052093351033.aspx) for more info.